# Can I add text to HTML that isn't copied when the user copies text on the page?

Tags: html, copy-paste

I'm writing a Javascript program that pretty prints some input as HTML. As part of that pretty printing, I add some text that isn't part of the original input (such as annotations, line numbers, etc.) But when the user copies from the page, it's a bunch of garbled text that isn't valid in the original format. Is there a way to prevent the text I added from getting copied?

Answer (score 0):

You can "steal" a solution from pastebin. They have two versions of code: 1 with pretty printing, and another below the pretty printed text in a scrollable textbox, code without pretty printing and other edits.